# How do you find a basis for the set of all $3 \times 3$ matrices whose rows and columns add up to zero?

Tags: linear-algebra

If $W$ is the set of all $3 \times 3$ matrices whose rows and columns add up to zero, how would you find a basis for this? There seem to be so many scenarios we'd need to cover, I can't find a way to succinctly find the answer / represent it well.

On a related note, how would you extend the basis to be a basis for $M_3(R)$? (I feel like I might be able to get this one, though, once I can clearly find a basis to begin with.)

Thanks in advance for the advice.

Comment: "a basis" in the body is correct; "the basis" in the title is wrong. The only vector space that has only one basis is $\mathbb F_2$.

Comment: Of course! Sorry - I just fixed that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Douglas' observation that the upper left $2\times2$ submatrix determines the remaining values suggests another solution: We can take the canonical basis for $2\times2$ matrices and fill in the third row and column for each of its elements; the result is

$$
\pmatrix{
1&0&-1\\
0&0&0\\
-1&0&1},
\pmatrix{
0&1&-1\\
0&0&0\\
0&-1&1},
\pmatrix{
0&0&0\\
1&0&-1\\
-1&0&1},
\pmatrix{
0&0&0\\
0&1&-1\\
0&-1&1}\;.
$$

Comment: That's even better!  In fact, this easily generalises to $n \times n$.

Comment: @Douglas: It also shows that your guess generalizes, since we can build all these by adding up some of your matrices.

Comment: It's kind of like sudoku.... neat. I guess you just need the intuition to see these things. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

**Guess**: I guess this is a basis: $$
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
1 & -1 & 0 \\
-1 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right),
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
0 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & -1 & 0 \\
-1 & 1 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right),
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
0 & 1 & -1 \\
0 & -1 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right),
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & -1 \\
0 & -1 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right).
$$

**Check**:  We know the vector space has dimension $4$ over $\mathbb{R}$, (or $\mathbb{Z}$), since once you fill in cells (1,1), (1,2), (2,1) (2,2), the rest is determined.

So, it is sufficient to show that
$$\left(\begin{array}{ccccccccc} 1 & -1 & 0 & -1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 
0 & 0 & 1 & -1 & 0 & -1 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & -1 & 0 & -1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & -1 & 0 & -1 & 1 \\ \end{array}\right)$$
has full rank (which I did on a computer).

Comment: Ah, a better guess than mine :-) (but also affording less opportunity to apply some linear algebra :-)

Answer (score 3):

You have six constraints, one for each row and column, but the sum of the row constraints and the sum of the column constraints are the same, so at most $5$ of the constraints are linearly independent, so the space is at least $4$-dimensional. The matrix of the first five constraints is

$$
\pmatrix{
1&1&1&0&0&0&0&0&0\\
0&0&0&1&1&1&0&0&0\\
0&0&0&0&0&0&1&1&1\\
1&0&0&1&0&0&1&0&0\\
0&1&0&0&1&0&0&1&0\\
}\;.
$$

We can guess three basis vectors by taking the three pairs of indices and placing a $\pmatrix{1&-1\\-1&1}$ matrix in the corresponding entries; that yields

$$
\pmatrix{
1&-1&0&-1&1&0&0&0&0\\
1&0&-1&0&0&0&-1&0&1\\
0&0&0&0&1&-1&0&-1&1
}
\;.
$$

Now we can take the generalized cross product of these $8$ vectors, both to check that they're all linearly independent and to find the fourth basis vector that's orthogonal to all of them. According to [Wolfram|Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=det%20%7B%7B1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0%7D,%7B0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0%7D,%7B0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1%7D,%7B1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0%7D,%7B0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0%7D,%7B1,-1,0,-1,1,0,0,0,0%7D,%7B1,0,-1,0,0,0,-1,0,1%7D,%7B0,0,0,0,1,-1,0,-1,1%7D,%7Ba,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i%7D%7D), the result is (proportional to)

$$
\pmatrix{0&1&-1&-1&0&1&1&-1&0}\;,
$$

so the matrix for one possible basis is

$$
\pmatrix{
1&-1&0&-1&1&0&0&0&0\\
1&0&-1&0&0&0&-1&0&1\\
0&0&0&0&1&-1&0&-1&1\\
0&1&-1&-1&0&1&1&-1&0
}
\;.
$$